# [apacheignite]Adding user-defined behavior to the Ignite Coordinator?

Tags: ignite

Is there a way to add a specific behavior that should only be executed on (and **follow**) the Ignite Coordinator ServerNode?

Is there a add-on hook to add some customer specific behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Greg

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is not any built-in hook to achieve this.
However, it can be achieved through **Node Singleton Ignite Service** and using an api on `TcpDiscoverySpi.isLocalNodeCoordinator()`.

If different discovery mechanism other than TcpDiscovery, is used, above mentioned way by @Alexandr can be used to get a co-ordinator node.

1. Define an Ignite Service as follows. It will schedule a task that will periodically execute on every node of the cluster and execute certain logic, if it's a coordinator node.

   public class IgniteServiceImpl implements Service {

   ```
    @IgniteInstanceResource
    Ignite ignite;

    @Override
    public void cancel(ServiceContext ctx) {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(ServiceContext ctx) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Starting a service");
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(ServiceContext ctx) throws Exception {

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Inside a service");
                if (ignite != null) {
                    DiscoverySpi discoverySpi = ignite.configuration().getDiscoverySpi();
                    if (discoverySpi instanceof TcpDiscoverySpi) {
                        TcpDiscoverySpi tcpDiscoverySpi = (TcpDiscoverySpi) discoverySpi;
                        if(tcpDiscoverySpi.isLocalNodeCoordinator())
                            doSomething();
                    } else {
                        ClusterNode coordinatorNode = ((IgniteEx) ignite).context().discovery().discoCache().oldestAliveServerNode();
                        UUID localNodeId = ((IgniteEx) ignite).context().localNodeId();
                        if(localNodeId.equals(coordinatorNode.id()))
                            doSomething();
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Ignite is null");
                }
            }
        }, 5, (30 * 1000L));
    }

    private void doSomething(){
        System.out.println("Hi I am Co-ordinator Node");
    }
   ```

   }
2. Start above service as node singleton using `Ignite.services()` as follows

   ```
    IgniteConfiguration igniteConfiguration = new IgniteConfiguration();
    igniteConfiguration.setIgniteInstanceName("ignite-node");
    Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(igniteConfiguration);

    IgniteServices services = ignite.services();
    services.deployNodeSingleton("test-service",new IgniteServiceImpl());
   ```

Comment: Awesome, this will work great!  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case of a low-level logic, you can extend Ignite with [custom plugins](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/plugins).
I'm not sure if there is an easy way to check if a node is indeed the coordinator, but you might check for the oldest one:

```
private boolean isCoordinator() {
        ClusterNode node = ((IgniteEx)ignite()).context().discovery().discoCache().oldestAliveServerNode();

        return node != null && node.isLocal();
    }
```

Otherwise, just run a custom initialization logic/compute task, once a node is started.